# Shrew VPN client doesn't create an adapter in Network Connections folder

Tags: windows, vpn, adapter

I've successfully set up and connected to a workplace VPN using [Shrew](http://shrew.net), but when I connect, no adapter appears in Windows' "Network Connections" folder. Consequently, I cannot find a way to share, bridge, or otherwise make it available to other network devices.

What I'm trying to achieve is using Internet Connection Sharing to allow an IP phone on my PC's *second* LAN adapter to connect to a server on my workplace network via the VPN connection established with Shrew.

I can see the Shrew-Soft-Virtual-Adapter-created *"Local Area Connection* 11"* using `ipconfig`; is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the way Shrew itself works, but *is* absolutally possible to create a connection that shows up in `ipconfig` and is fully functional without it having a driver installed or showing up in the network connections (6to4 connections are made this way).

You do it by using the [`netsh`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779693%28WS.10%29.aspx) commands. You may be able to share it that way, but I haven't done any real research into it.